# Proving a claim using a counter example

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $(q\neq 0)$, then $\frac { p }{ q } $ is rational.

Steps I took and my thoughts on this:

This seems awfully obvious, but yet I can't seem to organize my thoughts in any way to construct a formal mathematical proof. The most I can think of is as follows:

let $p=\frac { a }{ b } $ and $q=\frac { m }{ n }$; such that $a,b,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(m\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$, $n\neq 0)$

$$\frac { p }{ q } =\frac { \frac { a }{ b }  }{ \frac { m }{ n }  } =\frac { a }{ b } \cdot \frac { n }{ m } =\frac { an }{ bm } $$

$an$ and $bm$ are both integers because $a,b,m,n$ are all integers.

I imagine that this is way off. Please put me on the right path, and forgive my amateur attempt at a proof. I have a lot to learn about writing mathematical proofs, and I am just starting.

Comment: This looks fine.  Although, you also need the condition, $b\ne 0$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Fixed, but I need to use a counter example.

Comment: A counterexample can only show that a statement is false.  You must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Prove, or disprove using a counter example the following claim: $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $(q\neq 0)$, then $\frac { p }{ q } $ is rational.

Comment: OK, do you think the claim is true? or false?

Comment: I think that the claim is true

Comment: You are misreading the sentence. The phrase "using a counter example" is in the same clause as "disprove.

Comment: Read as:  (Prove) or (disprove using a counter example).

Comment: More clearly, they mean, prove, or if the the statement is false, disprove by using a counterexample.

Comment: If your mathematical proof is amateur, I recommend you buy and read the book, Numbers & Proofs by RBJT Allenby. Contains exercises too.

Comment: Oh!! Ok! My brain is no longer functioning. It's really late (or should I already say early?) and I'm trying to make time for discrete math, linear algebra, and calculus. My english comprehension went out the window. 

Is there anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: OK go with that, try to show it's true. If $q$ is a nonzero rational, is there another rational $r$ such that $qr = 1$? For example, what if $q = 2/3$.

Comment: wouldn't $r$ just have to be the reciprocal of $q$ for $qr=1$?

Comment: Yes exactly: the unique such $r$, actually, is $1/q$ alias $q^{-1}$. So that's a rational. Now, when you multiply any two rationals, you get another rational, not an irrational -- ya? (that's just like what you showed, only simpler). So $pq^{-1} = p(1/q) = p/q$ is a rational. That said, when you're learning, it's very worthwhile to be explicit and work through the details.

Comment: By the way, there's really nothing wrong with your proof! Possibly, yes, mention that $an$ and $bm$ are integers because a,n,b,m all are.

Comment: @BrianO Please look over the proof once more. I edited it and added details that I think make it more complete. I will also add (for closure) that since $a,b,m,n$ are integers, $\frac { an }{ bm } $ is rational

Comment: Yep that does it. Just one more thing: add "$\frac p q =$" to the front of the chain of equalities -- a nicety. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

That's not way off.  It's close.  In fact you are done and you were correct.

First figure out what rational means, we did that right: p = a/b, q = m/n a,b,m,n in Z, b, n ne 0.  Then you identified p/q = qm/bn and as qm, and bn are in Z and bn ne 0, p/q is rational.  You did it perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I might add would be using closure of integers for multiplication to show that the new numerator and denominator are themselves integers.